# Elasticsearch & Kibana environment per customer

Tags: security, elasticsearch, kibana, roles

We have many customers and many users per customer with different rights (admin, user). We would like to set elasticsearch and kibana with following constraints

- Each customer should have access only to his data
- No one can access the customer's environment (maybe access with permissions, password ?)
- Admin right can access, edit and do everything, and User right should can just see graphs and dashboards

Could you please help me and tell me how we can do it if it is possible, or maybe give me some references treating those subjects.

And also, how to separate data in elasticsearch (with clusters) ? a user from customerA shouldn't have access or search data related to customerB, please advice me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This should help you: https://www.elastic.co/blog/introducing-kibana-spaces-for-organization-and-security

Comment: Thank you for the link you have shared, that is for Kibana, and what about Elasticsearch ? I should have data separated per customer, so a user form customerA shouldn't be able to search data from customerB's index. How can I do that ?

Comment: Using x-pack plugin you can create user accounts eith access to specific indices

Comment: Thanks, and what about data organisation, is it better to create one cluster per customer ?

Comment: Ideally yes. Best to isolate each client’s data to their own elasticsearch cluster.

Comment: Thank you for confirmation @ben5556